# Ubuntu 14.04 Netflix-Desktop slow playback

Tags: pulseaudio, netflix, playback, netflix-desktop

so I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and then installed Netflix-Desktop. When I playback an video the audio plays back just fine, but the video is lagging behind a lot. Had this working on Linux Mint 16 just fine. My best bet is that it has something to do with pulseaudio, again...

System Setup:

Nvidia Geforce 580GTX with driver 331.38 installed

Dual Screen monitors

Asus p8z77-deluxe motherboard

Ask if you need any logs about anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. When installing Ubuntu I had to set nomodeset, noapic and nolapic in the grub boot editor. To bypass a system freeze glitch in the open sourced nouveau driver. I guess grub felt like remembering my previous boot settings after installing Ubuntu.

Solution:

From Terminal do

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Look for this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=off noapic nolapic nomodeset"`
3. Replace it with something like`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=on"`
4. `ctrl+o` To save and `ctrl+x` to exit nano
5. Next we have to update grub with the new settings `sudo update-grub`
6. Reboot the system.

Afterwords Netflix-Desktop, among other things, should work.

Also as a reminder you should first install the Nvidia drivers before anything, if you have a 580GTX. Otherwise nouveau will crash on you.